# Assigning to a static const member a value coming from a function (from a static method, to be more precise)

Tags: c++, c++98

The following is not allowed ('std::numeric_limits::max()' cannot appear in a constant-expression):

```
#include <limits>   

struct MyStruct {

private:  
  static const unsigned int INVALID_VALUE = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();

public:
  unsigned int index;

  inline MyStruct() : index(INVALID_VALUE) {}
};
```

Which could be the best way to obtain the desired behaviour? I would like, if possible, to have INVALID_VALUE to be known at compile time (e.g. to allow the compiler doing better optimization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about define your constant as  `~0U`. Since `unsigned int` is defined to be "direct binary representation", the inverse thereof should be all bits set.

Comment: This is perfect for my need, thank you! I have replaced it with `~static_cast<unsigned int>(0)`. Years and years working with C++, first time I realize about the tilde operator, weird!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UINT_MAX` from [`<climits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/climits) instead.

Alternatively, you can provide a definition:

```
struct MyStruct 
{
private:
  static const unsigned int INVALID_VALUE;
};

const unsigned int MyStruct::INVALID_VALUE = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();
```

Or, switch to C++11 where the function is `constexpr` and this is ok.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 or later, that should be fine since the `numeric_limits` functions are now declared `constexpr`.

If you're stuck in the past, then you'll need to define and initialise the constant outside the class:

```
// Header file
struct MyStruct {
    static const unsigned int INVALID_VALUE;
    // ...
};

// One source file
const unsigned int Mystruct::INVALID_VALUE = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();
```

Alternatively, you could use the `UINT_MAX` macro, defined in `<climits>`. This has the advantage that your constant will be usable in a constant expression.

Comment: I love the expression "stuck in the past" :D :D

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
const unsigned int mystruct::INVALID_VALUE = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();
```

somewhere in a cpp file, this is the normal way to initialize static members.